# show name function template name

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function wrapper class im trying to work on.

I want to be able to show the name of the function that is passed into the template.

```
template<auto Func>
struct FuncWrapper final {
    FuncWrapper() {
        StrFuncName = typeid(Func).name();
        std::cout << StrFuncName << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const { }

    std::string StrFuncName;
};

void Function() { }

FuncWrapper<Function> wrapper;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with standard C++. Demangling the typeid won't help either because you're only going to get the name of the **type** of the function, not the name you actually gave the function.

The closest you can get is the predefined [`__func__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition#func) constant, but that only exists inside the scope of the function you'd want to get the name of anyways.

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << __func__; // will print "foo"
}
```

Comment: i dont need tro pront the function name inside the function, i need the name of the passed function, to save it to set up stuff, its just anoying if i need to add it to the constructor.

Comment: I realize it's not quite what you want, hence why I said "the closest you can get".

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in standard C++, but some compiler/libraries may have a way to work around that.

For example, gcc's libstdc++ has an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) which could demangle a `typeid` value:

```cpp
#include <cxxabi.h>

std::cout << typeid(type).name() << " -> " abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(type).name(), 0, 0, 0) << std::endl
```

Comment: i sthere no wat to edit my FuncWrapper so i could use `#define GET_VARIABLE_NAME(Variable) (#Variable)`

Comment: there is also a github example called nameof, https://github.com/Neargye/nameof

Comment: I don't think there's any way to hack it into working without a compiler extension, because once you pass that function in as the template parameter, the only information you're left with is the type of and a pointer to the function.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement a *version* of this portably using `typeid`:

```
template<auto&>
struct symbol;
template<auto &S>
const char* name() {return typeid(symbol<S>).name();}
```

The name is of course **implementation-defined*; in practice, it may or may not require demangling (in addition to stripping the `symbol<…>` decoration).

There is the alternative approach of using commonplace compiler **extensions**:

```
template<auto &S>
const char* name() {return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;}
```

This too has to have the `const char * name<…>()` stripped.

Getting a function’s name from a **non-constant-expression** pointer to it is also possible but only via the use of a library that interprets the symbol table and/or debugging information.